# CGrigview select data from all pages

Tags: javascript, php, yii, cgridview

I have a `CGridview` containing huge amount of data (> 100000 row).

This gridview containing `CCheckbox` for each row and I need to choose some rows to make process to them.

[image]

The problem is that I can only apply the checking for a the rows displayed in the current page.

What I want is when applying some filter on the gridview and press the select All button (At the top right), the system select the rows from entire table (not from the current page only).
Is that possible??

Comment: I assume you have a button to submit your selected rows, so you can just check before send ids if checkAll is checked. If it's checked - pass your filters and you'll have all records with current filters. Try this out and post if it works.

Comment: I solve it by checking the value of (select All) parameter in the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by checking the value of (select All) parameter in the server side.

```
if ($_POST['grid_c7_all'] == "1") { ...
```